# SQL Conditional Date COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a case where I want to return the exchange rate of a currency, but if the date of the job is before 1/1/1999, then I want to just return the rate of 1/1/1999 since the exchange_rate table has no information before 1/1/1999.  So in this case, if the returned date from the COALESCE is 1/1/1985, the query should just instead join against 1/1/1999.

```
SELECT j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date, salary, salary_format_id, j.currency_id 
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN exchange_rate c1 ON CAST(COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) AS date) = c1.date AND c1.currency_id = j.currency_id
LEFT JOIN exchange_rate c2 ON CAST(COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) AS date) = c2.date AND c2.currency_id = 1
WHERE j.job_id = 4793
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) < '1999-01-01' THEN '1999-01-01'
  ELSE COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date)
END
```

And, yes, I know that's repetitive and a lot to type, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use case statement in select part

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN date < '1999-01-01' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [COLUMN_YOU_WANT] FROM exchange_rate AS c3 WHERE date = '1999-01-01' AND c3.currency_id = j.currency_id)
      ELSE c1.[COLUMN_YOU_WANT]
   END, j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, ...
```

Basically it says if date < '1999-01-01' select the rate for '1999-01-01', otherwise just use what you get from JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you want:

```
LEFT JOIN exchange_rate c2 ON (
CASE 
 WHEN (CAST(COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) AS date)) < '1999-01-01' THEN '1999-01-01'
 ELSE CAST(COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) AS date) END) = c2.date AND c2.currency_id = 1
```

Not sure if you actually need the casts with coalesce. (And removing them seem to work fine, but maybe there is some case when you need to cast.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear, but I think this is all you need:

```
    LEFT JOIN exchange_rate c1
    on
    (case when 
    CAST(COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) AS date) < '1999-01-01'
    then '1999-01-01'
    else
    CAST(COALESCE(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.reported_date, j.start_date) AS date)
   end ) = c1.date
```